# Mac Pro Randomly Restarts

Tags: mac-pro, restart

I have a MacPro from Early 2007, and it will restart and at random times. It's not even at times where I'm doing something graphically, RAM-wise, or processor-wise intensive. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I could do to isolate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to start with the Apple Hardware Test:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1509?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: I tried holding down D, and it didn't work. It keeps going to the standard login page.

Comment: That is weird. At least for the mid 2007 model it should work (see also the manual: http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/macbook_mid2007_userguide.pdf). I can't seem to find any specific information on the early 2007 model. There is some information on this issue in this link: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3549995?start=0&tstart=0 It suggests also holding the option key (thus hold 'd' and option while booting). Have you tried that?

Comment: Well that first guide was for a MacBook Pro, and I'm having trouble with a MacPro.